# Loops only executing first iteration inside bytefield environment

Tags: loops, bytefield

I have a situation where I want a diagram of 16 registers that machine has. I've tried this code, which does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bytefield}
\begin{document}
\newcount\X
\X=0
\begin{bytefield}
  \loop
     \bitbox{16}{r\the\X}
     \advance \X by 1
   \ifnum \X<16
   \repeat
\end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```

This results in only the first iteration being printed.

Comment: Please, add a sample of what the output should look like; I tried to guess, but there is possibly something else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a loop that starts in an alignment cell and ends in another. Since `bytefield` is built upon alignments, that kind of loop is out of the question.

A different looping mechanism can be used.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makebitboxes}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { #1 - 1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \bitbox{ 1 }{ #2 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {~}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=2em]{8}
\makebitboxes{16}{r#1}
\end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```

In the first argument of `\makebitboxes` you specify the number of bits; the second argument is a template, where `#1` stands for the current bit number in the loop.

[image]

If you want a different output, which might be the object of your question, you have to use the number of bits to occupy and add `\\` to end lines.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makebitboxes}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { #1 - 1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \bitbox{ #1 }{ #2 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{bytefield}{8}
\bitheader{0-15}\\
\makebitboxes{16}{r#1}
\end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```

[image]